# consuming an external web service using marklogic

Tags: web-services, xquery, marklogic

Having a difficult time. Finding examples on, How to access an external web service using marklogic?  (maybe my search terms are wrong? i also tried `xdmp:http-get`, `xdmp:http-post`, post http request, `mash-up`, orchestrate).

I first need to understand, How difficult (hopefully easy) it will be for me to write a script in `MarkLogic` to access one external (non-ML) web service and display the response before I proceed with combining results from 3 different web services (is the correct term for this mash-up?) in one page using ML.

An example using ML will be most appreciated. I have seen **celsius** to **fahrenheit** conversion examples, also stock quotes request and response but not in ML. I do not know how or where to start. Can you point me to right direction please. Eager to learn using ML for web services.

many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say there are examples here: http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-post

But for the sake of completeness, let me add these as well:

> Based on:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=FahrenheitToCelsius

SOAP 1.1:

```
let $envelop :=
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
        <Fahrenheit>100</Fahrenheit>
      </FahrenheitToCelsius>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
return
  xdmp:http-post(
    "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
      <headers>
        <Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
        <SOAPAction>"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/FahrenheitToCelsius"</SOAPAction>
      </headers>
    </options>,
    $envelop
  )
```

SOAP 1.2:

```
let $envelop :=
  <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
      <FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
        <Fahrenheit>100</Fahrenheit>
      </FahrenheitToCelsius>
    </soap12:Body>
  </soap12:Envelope>
return
  xdmp:http-post(
    "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
      <format xmlns="xdmp:document-get">xml</format>
      <headers>
        <Content-Type>application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
      </headers>
    </options>,
    $envelop
  )
```

HTTP POST:

```
let $body := text {
  string-join(
    ("Fahrenheit=" || encode-for-uri(string(100))),
    "&amp;"
  )
}
return
  xdmp:http-post(
    "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius",
    <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
      <headers>
        <Content-Type>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</Content-Type>
      </headers>
    </options>,
    $body
  )
```

HTH!

Comment: thank you very much.  your reply examples made things clearer to me, reading more on the ml xdmp:http-post.

Comment: i am not clear on this though: if i consume 3 web services in one page, all i need to do is write 3 let $envelop := .... return xdmp:http-post(...) FLOWR blocks as in your examples?  thanks again for your patient replies to an ML/xquery newbie.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping each call in a function to make it easier, and then have something like `let $res1 := my:func1(..) let $res2 := my:funky(..) return <results>{$res1, $res2}</results>` to glue results together..

Comment: If not clear enough, post a separate question, comments are too short to explain nicely..